# I couldn't find my.ini files on root directory?

Tags: mysql

I trying to switch my mysql database to different location. But i could not find my.ini files to change 'datadir' variable?

Instead there are other files like my-huge.ini, my-large.ini, my-small.ini, etc....

Thanks in advance,
Shiv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is that you take one of the supplied files that best suits your needs and copy it to be your `my.ini`.

If you intend to use a small database, for example,

```
copy  my-small.ini my.ini
```

Then edit the `my.ini` to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks Michael and my-small.ini doesn't have datadir. Is that ok if add the variable? 
datadir=d:\path

Comment: @user1197461 Yes, just add whatever variables you need.

Answer (score 0):

my.ini is located in `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5` (not Program Files)

NB: ProgramData is a hidden folder